# I am trying to pass a value from a UICollectionView Item to a UIButton in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, didset

I have a `UICollectionViewCell`. This Cell is registered in another UICollectionViewCell, which in turn is registered in `viewDidLoad` of a `UIViewController` called `FilterCollectionViewController`. When the first cell is selected it should pass a value of type String to a `UIButton`. This UIButton is located in `FilterCollectionViewController`

In the `FilterCollectionViewController` I made a variable called `colorName`

```
var colorName: String!{
    didSet {
        print(colorName)
    }
}
```

in the same class there is a `UIButton`.

```
@objc func addButtonFunc(sender:UIButton){
    print(colorName)
    }
```

In `FilterCollectionViewController` I declare a `UICollectionView`. Within this collectionView there is a "second"  `UICollectionView`, which has the function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let filterVC = FilterCollectionViewController()
    filterVC.colorName = "blau"    
}
```

When clicking on a cell from the second `UICollectionView` I can print the colorName value, from the `didSet` (in the main `FilterCollectionViewController`). However, I want it to be passed to the `UIButton`. When this UIButton is clicked it should process this string further. However the `print` method results in `nil`

Comment: are you doing segue to pass the variable?

Comment: I do not use segue

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `FilterCollectionViewController` in your `didSelectItemAt` method. I am assuming `FilterCollectionViewController` is the one which has the `colorName` property and the collectionview?

Comment: Also, where will the button be? Inside the collectionviewcell? And how do you want to process it?

Comment: NSNoob, you are right. the button is however outside of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new instance of `FilterCollectionViewController` if you are in the same class, other things look fine,

Create a variable like,

```
var colorName: String {
    didSet {
        print(colorName)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    colorName = "blau"  
}
```

Then in `addButton` action,

```
@objc func addButton(sender: UIButton){
    print(colorName)
}
```

Comment: I edited my Question. The cell is registered in the same ViewController, but it is in another class. That is the only way I can access the same value.

Comment: if I declare the variable in the ` UIViewController` I cannot see it within the `didSelectItem` function. If I declare it in the `UICollectionViewCell` I cannot see it in the ÙIViewController`

Comment: I don't get it now if everything is in same view controller it should be accessible within the class right?

Comment: Can you please share the updated `FilterCollectionViewController` class file itself in question for better understanding.

Comment: exactly. I mean I can access it from the same viewController, it is just that the value is not passed to the UIButton.

Comment: Please share the updated `FilterCollectionViewController` class file's code if possible

Comment: I sent the whole thing. Almost

Comment: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    colorName = "blau"  
}` - this is followed right?

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let filterVC = FilterCollectionViewController()
    filterVC.colorName = "blau"    
}

Comment: please remove `let filterVC = FilterCollectionViewController()`

Comment: Sorry. The collectionView is within another collection view. So I have two collection views. You are right. But it still does not work with two `UICollectionView`s

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go to storyboard and set **identifier** "yourViewId"  to

FilterCollectionViewController

then

in this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"yourViewId") as! FilterCollectionViewController
viewController.colorName = "red"
self.present(viewController, sender:nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use storyboard. I also do not know what instant I sting the same view controller would bring

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem.

In the parent `FilterCollectionViewController` I made a variable `colorName` like

```
var colorName: String!
```

in the second `UIVieControllerCell` I declared a variable of the Parent ViewController Class

```
var colorName: FilterCollectionViewController?
```

Thereby in the second UICollectionView at the function `didSelectItemsAt`I added the following code

```
colorName?.colorName = "blau"
```

This had to be declared again in the first `UICollectionview`, the parent of the second `UICollectionView` and a child of `FilterCollectionViewController`. The declaration was in the function `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.colorName = self
```

And that is it. The color name is updated when clicking the button.

Here is the abbreviated Code:

```
class FilterCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var colorName: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//...register UICollectionview declare button etc.
}

 @objc func addButtonFunc(sender:UIButton){  
    print(colorName)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! FilterCell

        cell.colorName = self

        return cell
    }
```

And in the FilterCell class:

```
var colorName: FilterCollectionViewController?
//Class is initialised with  function, in the function another UUICollectionView is registered.
//...functions like numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAt are declared

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    colorName?.colorName = "blau"

}
```